# CS7069 Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, oledb

I am currently to connect my project to Microsoft Access DataBase in my project.
I added `System.Data.dll` as the reference so the `OleDbConnection` command can be work but the command `conn.Open()` has error. The error statement is "Reference to type `Component` claims it is defined in `System`, but it could not be found".

Is that possible `System.dll` and `System.Data.dll` overlap?

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace App3
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void me_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data            Source=C:\Users\chinwuen\Documents\psm.accdb";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into psm (intensity, humidity) Values('1', '2')");
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}      
  }
```

[image: Error statement]
[image: Coding]

Comment: Write your code, don't use screenshots.

Comment: Which .NET Framework you application is targeting to?

Comment: Try Build->Clean, Build -> Rebuild Solution. Also try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: hey everyone, 
Sorry for bring trouble to you all.
I already add the source code.Thank you for your help

Comment: My application is using .net Core and target is window 8.1

Comment: I don't think that .NET Core [supports OLEDB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/)